# pic(1): graphic cut off at right border

Tags: images, image-manipulation, groff

I created a graphic in the `pic` language as follows (`v-modell.pic`):

```
.PS
AF: box wid 1.6 ht 0.25 "Anforderungen"
SA: box same "Systemarchitektur" at AF.se + (0.1, -0.5)
KA: box same "Komponentenarchitektur" at SA.se + (0.1, -0.5)
MS: box same "Modulspezifikation" at KA.se + (0.1, -0.5)
IM: box same "Implementierung" at MS.se + (0.1, -0.5)
UT: box same "Unittests" at IM.ne + (0.1, 0.5)
IT: box same "Integrationstests" at UT.ne + (0.1, 0.5)
ST: box same "Systemtests" at IT.ne + (0.1, 0.5)
AT: box same "Abnahmetests" at ST.ne + (0.1, 0.5)

arrow from AF.s to SA.n - (0.25, 0) ->
arrow from SA.s to KA.n - (0.25, 0) ->
arrow from KA.s to MS.n - (0.25, 0) ->
arrow from MS.s to IM.n - (0.25, 0) ->
arrow from IM.n + (0.25, 0) to UT.s ->
arrow from UT.n + (0.25, 0) to IT.s ->
arrow from IT.n + (0.25, 0) to ST.s ->
arrow from ST.n + (0.25, 0) to AT.s ->

arrow dotted "validiert durch" above from AF.e to AT.w ->
arrow dotted from SA.e to ST.w ->
arrow dotted from KA.e to IT.w ->
arrow dotted from MS.e to UT.w ->
.PE
```

Running Arch Linux, I generate the output thereof as follows:

```
$ pic v-modell.pic | pic2graph -colorspace RGB -density 150 -format png >v-modell.png
```

The result: the graphic is cut off at the right hand side:

[image: output of pic/pic2graph, cropped at the right-hand side]

Is there a way to increase the width of the canvas?

Comment: One option is to use `scale` in the `.pic` file. I.e. after the `.PS` line say `scale=1.2`

Comment: @ibuprofen looks promising, but also requires up-scaling the existing boxes with much text in it. So I'd have to re-work the entire graphic. But it's certainly worth considering next time when I'm still working on the graphic!

Comment: Yes. It's not ideal either. One should hope setting `maxpswid` to a higher value would work, but looks like there is a limit. At least here setting lower values "works" but not higher.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Instead of using `pic2graph`, I use `groff` and set a bigger page size. Then I need `ps2eps`, of which the output can be processed by ImageMagick's `convert`:

```
pic <v-modell.pic | groff -Tps -P-pa3 | ps2eps | convert -colorspace RGB -density 150 -format PNG - v-modell.png
```

Not ideal, but works:

[image: the final working output]